# How to use WebAssembly (wasm) with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, webassembly

I use `create-react-app` and library with `wasm` its called [sax-wasm](https://github.com/justinwilaby/sax-wasm#usage-for-the-web). 
Slightly modifying the sample code for the web I got this:

```
import { SaxEventType, SAXParser } from 'sax-wasm';

async function loadAndPrepareWasm() {
  const saxWasmResponse = await import('sax-wasm/lib/sax-wasm.wasm');
  const saxWasmbuffer = await saxWasmResponse.arrayBuffer();
  const parser = new SAXParser(SaxEventType.Attribute | SaxEventType.OpenTag, {
    highWaterMark: 64 * 1024,
  });

  const ready = await parser.prepareWasm(new Uint8Array(saxWasmbuffer));
  if (ready) {
    return parser;
  }
}

loadAndPrepareWasm().then(console.log);
```

When I running `yarn start` command my build is failed:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/sax-wasm/lib/sax-wasm.wasm
Module parse failed: magic header not detected
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: magic header not detected
```

Comment: I assume [this is the appropriate upstream issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6457) to track / upvote.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution is for CRA 3.x. For CRA 4.x you should use [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco).

CRA does not support WASM. But you can workaround it. You need to override webpack config. There are multiple packages that can do it. I used [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). And you need the wasm-loader package

Than add your override *config-overrides.js*:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {

    /**
     * Add WASM support
     */

    // Make file-loader ignore WASM files
    const wasmExtensionRegExp = /\.wasm$/;
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.wasm');
    config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
        (rule.oneOf || []).forEach(oneOf => {
            if (oneOf.loader && oneOf.loader.indexOf('file-loader') >= 0) {
                oneOf.exclude.push(wasmExtensionRegExp);
            }
        });
    });

    // Add a dedicated loader for WASM
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: wasmExtensionRegExp,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: [{ loader: require.resolve('wasm-loader'), options: {} }]
    });

    return config;
};
```

In *package.json* I did it like this:

```json
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-app-rewired": "2.1.3",
    "wasm-loader": "1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! For me the solution was half of this. I just had to make the file-loader ignore .wasm files. When I added a dedicated loader for WASM it didn't work. Also, setting `"type": "javascript/auto"` for .wasm files didn't work for me either. (I'm using wasm-bindgen)

Comment: Note: in order to be able to load wasm files, your webserver needs to support wasm , returning wasm mime type as application/wasm

Comment: For me, `wasm-loader` needed to be replaced with `file-loader`.

Comment: What does this mean ?  You first say someone needs to use craco, then you proceed to show you someone doesn't need to use craco ?  I'm confused. 
I just wanna code my app, and this is so frustrating.  Please be clear in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You eventually want to use the wasm inside the browser. That means you have to access it inside the browser.

I installed [esbuild-wasm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-wasm). There are two ways to set up this:

1- in node modules find the the module "node_modules/esbuild-wasm" you will see a file "esbuild-wasm" and place it inside public folder. This has the compiled code can directly work inside the browser. Inside component:

```typescript
import * as esbuild from "esbuild-wasm"
import {useRef, useState} from "react"

// you can use ref to keep a reference to any Js value inside of a component. 
const ref=useRef()
const startEsbuildService=async()=>{
   // this object is responsible for transpiling
   ref.current=await esbuild.startService({
   worker:true,
   // we are pointing to the public directory
   wasmURL:'/esbuild.wasm'})
}
```

2nd way:

```typescript
const startEsbuildService = async () => {
    ref.current = await esbuild.startService({
      worker: true,
      // unpkg.com provides all npm modules without CORS error
      wasmURL: "https://unpkg.com/esbuild-wasm@0.8.42/esbuild.wasm",
    });
  };
```

This is how you use it

```typescript
 // you store the code
    const [codeInput,setCodeInput]=useState("")
    const [transpiledCode,setTranspiledCode]=useState("")
const onClick= async ()=>{
   if(!ref.current) return;
   const transformedCode=await ref.current.transform(codeInput,{
      // es-build can handle different types of code
      loader:'jsx',
      target: 'es2015'})
   // this will rerender our component
   setTranspiledCode(transformedCode)
}
```