# How to load a wasm module with create-react-library?

Tags: reactjs, npm, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to make a react library using `create-react-library` that uses webassembly, however, when the project is run I get the following error.

```
Failed to compile.

/path/to/bar/pkg/bar_bg.wasm
Module parse failed: magic header not detected
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: magic header not detected
```

My setup is as follows:

1. Create a wasm Rust project:

```sh
wasm-pack new bar
```

2. Add a simple function to `lib.rs`:

```rust
use js_sys;
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn name() -> js_sys::JsString {
    "Nic".into()
}
```

3. Add js-sys as a dependency to `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
js-sys="0.3.45"
```

4. Build wasm project:

```sh
wasm-pack build
```

5. Create a react library:

```sh
cd ..
create-react-library foo --skip-prompts --template typescript
```

6. Add bar (wasm) as a dependency of foo (react lib):

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../bar/pkg"
  },
```

7. Edit `foo/src/index.tsx` to:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.css'

import { name } from "bar";

interface Props {
  text: string
}

export const ExampleComponent = ({ text }: Props) => {
return <div className={styles.test}>Example Component:  ({name()}) {text}</div>
}
```

8. In one terminal:

```sh
cd foo && npm i && npm start
```

9. In another terminal:

```sh
cd foo/example && npm i && npm start
```

Error at the top is produced at this point.

Comment: Maybe a flavor of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478832/wasm-react-module-parse-failed-magic-header-not-detected

Comment: I answered it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319775/how-to-use-webassembly-wasm-with-create-react-app/66911353#66911353